# android custom layout for listview of sqlite database

Tags: java, android

i need to make custom layout for my list view where data source is a sqlite database
when i run this code my output Thus shows  (name next to  phone) but i need to display output like this (phone under
                  name)
this is my code

```
 here public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
List<Todo> todos;
MyDataBase db = new MyDataBase(this);
String m,m1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     todos = db.getallcontacts();

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,todos);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            m = editText.getText().toString();
            m1 = editText1.getText().toString();
            db.AddnewContact(new Todo(m, m1));
            adapter.add(new Todo(m, m1));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "contact saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                final int position, long rowId) {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            adb.setMessage("you need to delete this contact");
            adb.setPositiveButton("delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Todo td = todos.get(position);
                    db.deleteContact(td);
                    adapter.remove(td);
                }
            });
            adb.show();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

my database calss

```
 here public class MyDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
 final String KEY_NAME = "name";
final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public MyDataBase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void AddnewContact (Todo todo)// this method to add new contact
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME,todo.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, todo.getPhoneNumber());
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public Todo getContact(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS,new String[] { KEY_ID,
        KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO },KEY_ID + "=?",new String[] { String.valueOf(id) },null,null,null,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Todo contact = new Todo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}
public List<Todo> getallcontacts()
{
    List<Todo> contactList = new ArrayList<Todo>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Todo contact = new Todo();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
public void deleteContact(Todo contact) {
    int id = contact.getID();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID
            + " = " + id, null);
    db.close();
}
public Cursor fetchAllCountries() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor mCursor = database.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {KEY_ID,
                    KEY_NAME,KEY_PH_NO},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

}

my todo calss

```
           `enter public class Todo {
//private variables
int _id;
String _name;
String _phone_number;

// Empty constructor
public Todo(){

}
// constructor
public Todo(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}

// constructor
public Todo(String name, String _phone_number){
    this._name = name;
    this._phone_number = _phone_number;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this._name = name;
}

// getting phone number
public String getPhoneNumber(){
    return this._phone_number;
}

// setting phone number
public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
    this._phone_number = phone_number;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return  _name+" "+_phone_number;
}
```

}

`

Comment: used custom adapter . like class your_adapter_class extend BaseAdapter

Comment: but BaseAdapter class dont have add method like ArrayAdapter and i need add method to add name and phone to list view

Comment: Ok do one thing create add function in baseadapter . Its customers and u have full control . Please read carefully baseadapter and let me know ill send u code